# $addToSet in update aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB update aggregation pipeline which I need to extend with $addToSet as I want to new elements to an array but I cannot mange to make it work with the aggregation pipeline.

MongoDB Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9f_rS2QjLR_

Document to update:

```json
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arr": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ]
  }
```

Aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "arr": {
        $addToSet: {
          "$arr": {
            $each: [
              "bar",
              "baz"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Expected output:

```json
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "arr": [
      "foo",
      "bar",
      "baz"
    ]
  }
```

If it isn't possible to use the $addToSet operator how can I manually create the same behaviour using other operators?

Answer (score 2):

**1. **`$addToSet` with Normal Update Query**** (duplicate values will be removed)
[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7iR7M_CBzlv)

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    arr: "baz"
  }
})
```

If you want to add multiple elements into array use `$each` like
[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/inQTw-tgbGu)

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    arr: {
      $each: [
        "baz",
        "abc",
        "def"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

**2. can use `$concatArrays` with aggregation** (duplicate values not removed)
[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6aBxgQtJSLP)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$arr",
          [
            "baz",
            "abc",
            "bar"  //will be duped
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for
> update operations. With the update operations, the aggregation
> pipeline can consist of the following stages: `$addFields $set $project $unset $replaceRoot $replaceWith`

therefore can use `$project`    [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_RNkyY3bxEv)

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$arr",
          [
            "baz",
            "abc",
            "bar"  //will be duped
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**3. can use `$setUnion` with aggregation** (duplicate values will be removed)
[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wi2FMQqtYpv)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $setUnion: [
          "$arr",
          [
            "baz",
            "abc",
            "bar"  //will not be duped
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

or
[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LzpS-DDU0lM)

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $setUnion: [
          "$arr",
          [
            "baz",
            "abc",
            "bar"   //will not be duped
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but that solution does not make use if the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: No, since `db.collection.update` can take a pipeline: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: @quieri i added an implementation with your suggestion as well

Comment: Thanks, but concat arrays will actually create duplicates in the array which is not the desired in this case

Comment: @quieri ah yeah forgot that. in that case try setUnion

Comment: i cant seem to find an easier way with addtoset since it supports only group and a few other pipelines in aggregations

Answer (score 1):

This code keeps an order and adds new items to the end of array.

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  _id: 1
}, [{
    $set: {
      arr: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $ifNull: ["$arr", []]
          },
          {
            $filter: {
              input: ['bar', 'baz'],
              as: "item",
              cond: {
                $eq: [{
                  $indexOfArray: [
                    {
                      $ifNull: ["$arr", []]
                    },
                    "$$item"
                  ]
                }, -1]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Also, keep in mind, that $project clause will remove all fields in document which it doesn't specify.